# Changing config.json file containing functions breaks site

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net

I have some Javascript that calls a config.json file that contains a list of functions that point to vb.net code.  When I add a function to the config file, the site stops loading properly.  Using Firebug, I see that it's hung up on the config file.  The function exists in my vb code and is called in the javascript.  I'm sorry to be so vague, but I can't upload any code since I'm at work.  I mostly just want to know if anybody knows why this could be happening.

Comment: [Try parsing your JSON file here](http://jsonlint.com/) to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Thanks!  That told me what the problem is, at least.  I gotta figure out how to fix it now.

Comment: NP. Most likely errors are missing quotes around keys/values and missing commas.

Comment: And it's fixed.  I'll bookmark that site.  I really appreciate the link.